# How bypass n+1, correct domain -> ViewModel.FromMyDomain approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, nhibernate, viewmodel

let say I have one entity with some fields and one collection like this

```
Entity
int Id {get; set;}
string Name {get; set;}
string Title {get; set;}
List<Order>Orders {get; set;}

Order
int Id {get; set;}
string Name {get; set;}
Entity Entity {get; set;}
```

Now I want to create EntityOrderViewModel which will represent only few properties from both entitites. Like this

```
EntityOrderViewModel
int Id {get; set;}
string EntityName {get; set;}
string EntityTitle {get; set;}
string OrderName {get; set;}
int OrderId {get; set;}

EntityOrderViewModel(Entity x)
{
   Id = 1; 
   EntityName = x.Name; 
   EntityTitle = x.Title;
   foreach(Order order in x.Orders)
   {
      OrderName = order.Name;
   }
}

public static List<EntityOrderViewModel> FromMyDomain(IList<Entity> x)
{
    List<EntityOrderViewModel> vm= new List<EntityOrderViewModel>();

    foreach (Entity e in x)
    {
        vm.Add(new EntityOrderViewModel(e));
    }
    return vm;
}
```

Now from my controller I want to call all entities like this

```
//opensession
   // open transaction
      List<Entity> data = session.Query<Entity>().ToList();
   //end transaction
      transaction.commit();
//end session      
      return EntityOrderViewModel.FromMyDomain(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have your session in the controller, why not hydrate the view model directly ?

```
from entity in session.Query<Entity>()
join order in session.Query<Order> join entity.EntityId on order.Entity.EntityId
select new EntityOrderDTO // or anon 
{
  EntityId = entity.EntityId,
  Name = entity.Name,
  OrderName = order.OrderName
}
```

join will take care of your n+1

Comment: I'd rather not use joins, they scares me :) If I understand I can use inside my session new EntityViewModel{ Id = entity.Id} etc. ?

Comment: joins scare you ! dude :) ! when you project i.e. EntityId = entity.EntityId, corresponding sql projection is generated. If you did select entity then tried to translate it you would then have a n+1 situation entity --> Orders. **Join** is perfectly exceptable / reasonable and the only solution when data is stored multiple tables, Thus to sum it up you either join in your query or in your mappings either ways join is going to happen

Comment: ok, join(t) it is. I guess I have to learn it. Thanks though.